# When Intellij Idea show tips "add lib XXXXXX to classpath"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I already add library to pom.xml,but when I press alt + enter the Intellij Idea give tips: add library to classpath. The question is what may trigger this situation and how to avoid this in Intellij Idea?

[image]

Comment: An error in your pom? Forgetting to refresh the project?

Comment: make sure you can build by Maven from command line: `mvn build`, then refresh project in Maven tool window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post `mvn clean install` is successful go to `File => Maven => Synchronise`

or

use command `mvn -U idea:idea`. This will refresh complete cache.